# Two sub select query inside a where condition in laravel5?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, laravel-5

I want to compare two select query inside where condition of a query in Laravel5,

The `where` condition of my query in laravel is given below,but it is not wokring.

ie,`select from invoice where (select query1) == (select query2)`.

```
 $invoice->orWhere(function($query) {
                $query->where('invoices.status', '=', InvoiceStatusConstant::SENT)
                        ->where('invoices.due_date', '<', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
                        ->where(DB::raw('(SELECT ROUND(SUM(invoice_items.quantity*invoice_items.rate), 2) from invoice_items'), '=',
                                DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) from payments "));
            });
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: You can't compare queries you need to compare values..

Comment: comparing query means comparing values,each query select a value :)

Answer (score 0):

DB::raw won't give you a value. It's just a way to create an expression. If you wanna do it that way, you should use:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) from payments"))
```

but this will give you an array. So, I'd do the following:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) as pay from payments"))[0]->pay
```

or even easier

```
DB::select("(SELECT SUM(payments.amount) as pay from payments")[0]->pay
```